# How to update docker volume from inside a container?

Tags: docker

I have two docker containers connected through a frontendbuild docker volume:

```
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/nginx_ssltls/Dockerfile
    #restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./compose/production/nginx_live:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      - staticfiles_harcelement:/app/static
      - mediafiles_harcelement:/app/media
      - frontendbuild:/usr/share/nginx/html/build
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
    networks:
      - network_app
  react
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/frontend/Dockerfile
    #restart: always
    volumes:
      - frontendbuild:/app/frontend/build
    networks:
      - network_app
```

Each time i re-run my build, the volume is not updated with the updated /app/frontend/build folder from the updated react docker container.

I have found how to update a volume from a folder on my host machine, but this time the build is created in the Dockerfile, so the files I need to update to the volume are inside the container...

How can i automatize this in code?

Here is result of docker inspect volume :

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2022-07-07T19:37:23+02:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "app-harcelement",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.25.0",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "frontendbuild"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/frontendbuild/_data",
        "Name": "frontendbuild",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

Thank you

Comment: You can use `docker-compose down -v` to delete the volumes when you take the containers down. When you then bring them back up, the containers will be created and and the contents from the image copied to them.

Comment: I dont want all the volumes to be deleted...

Comment: Volumes are a mechanism to store _data_ across container restarts; their design point isn't to publish files from one image to a different container.  If you're looking at a React application (that just gets compiled down to static files and served), can you build it in a multi-stage build, and remove both the volume and the separate container?

Comment: [Named Docker volume to share build not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774522/named-docker-volume-to-share-build-not-updating) seems to basically match your situation; that has a sample container entrypoint script that manually updates the volume on container startup.

Comment: hi, thanks! i dont want to do a multi stage build because my nginx container will share and serve several react builds for different websites...